# How to write a SQL query that selects one of the comma separated values in the column

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my SQL Server table, there is a column in which I have comma separated values.

For example: in column `AllSegmentsList` and the values in the column are like `'a, b, c,d, e'` .

Now, I my query I want to say

```
select * 
from table 
   if one of the the entries out of all the comma separated values in that column is 'b'
```

but I want to make sure that the query can handle spaces on either sides of commas, if are present(not always).

Comment: @juergend: SQL server management studio

Comment: Are the spaces present after the commas?

Comment: @DavidG : No, there are not any spaces at the moment but I wanted to make sure that if tomorrow someone adds them to the system, it should not break off

Comment: Then the answer you accepted is wrong :)

Comment: ahh, right! I realized it but none of the answers yet can handle that problem  :)Still open to answers :)

Comment: My last option handles both or you can modify the one you accepted to do it both ways.

Comment: I didn't have the information of the white spaces initially, I have now changed my answer to make the one liner work in every case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It kind of depends on your data. If no value contains a space, following should work

```
 select
   *
 from
   table
 where
   replace(concat(',', slist, ','), ' ', '') like '%,b,%';
```

Comment: Actually looking for one that can handle if spaces get in there at any point of time :)

Comment: in the value itself or just before or after the comma? Is something like this possible "h,e,l,o,i am human,foo"?

Comment: Just before or after the comma. not in the value

Comment: then my solution should work. Actually it's quite straight forward. I'm just appending and prepending a single ',' to the column (so  I don't have to handle a match at the beginning or end). Afterwards replacing every space in the column (so I don't have to handle the "edge cases" ", a" and "a ,". Afterwards it's a simple like expression.. maybe the functions may differ in mssql but it works fine in mysql

Comment: Thank you for this different one, but just wanted to confirm that in replace function, should not it have AllSegmentsList as first parameter and space as second?

Comment: You're right I put the arguments in the wrong order. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Comment: ok, okay, yes. Just differs in how parameters are passed in replace function of SQl. Thank you :)

Comment: this won't work if there are spaces in between the string being searched for

Answer (score 2):

this should work in all cases:

```
 select * from tablename where replace(replace(','+allsegmentslist+',',', ',','),' ,',',') like '%,b,%'
```

Comment: What if the text appears at the start or end like `a,b`?

Comment: No it won't as there is no comma after the b.

Comment: it will because I'm adding it to allsegmentlist

Comment: Ah, I see that now, enough for +1 though I wonder which method is most efficient.

Comment: Also, as pointed out by @Brian, the original post has spaces after the commas.

Comment: this is incomplete as well.. what if there're is than one space before or after the comma

Answer (score 1):

If you are fine with finding only substrings, this will do:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE allsegmentslist like '%b%'
```

However if you need to search for the full length text and not substring, this will work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename 
WHERE allsegmentslist like '%b,%'
OR allsegmentslist like '%,b%'
OR allsegmentslist like '%,b,%'
OR allsegmentslist = 'b'
```

If there are spaces after the commas, you will need to change to this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename 
WHERE allsegmentslist like '%b,%'
OR allsegmentslist like '%, b%'
OR allsegmentslist like '%, b,%'
OR allsegmentslist = 'b'
```

Alternatively if the commas only sometimes have spaces after them, you will need this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename 
WHERE allsegmentslist like '%b,%'
OR allsegmentslist like '%,b%'
OR allsegmentslist like '%,b,%'
OR allsegmentslist = 'b'
OR allsegmentslist like '%, b%'
OR allsegmentslist like '%, b,%'
```

Comment: In his sample there is a space after the comma and before the value

Comment: @BrianDeMilia Hmm indeed, I've asked for clarification. Will edit if he says they are needed.

Comment: @BrianDeMilia I've just included all possibilities instead!

Comment: probably the way to go... I'm not the one who downvoted you by the way, not sure what that's about

Comment: @BrianDeMilia I don't mind the downvotes, they happen frequently on here!

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the LIKE operator:

```
select *
  from tablename
 where allsegmentslist like '%, b,%'
    or allsegmentslist like 'b,%'
    or allsegmentslist like '%, b'
    or allsegmentslist = 'b'
```

Comment: What if you are searching for `bob` and the database contains `fred,bobby,andy`?

Comment: Closer, but what if the text is at the end?

Comment: Should have that as '%, b' now.